# How do I pop up a menu on hovering over an image in Java?

Tags: java

I am writing a ludo game in Java. I am trying to figure out how to: when hovering my mouse over playable token, a pop menu is displayed showing results that token can play.

Comment: Is it an android based game?

Comment: Add a tag or mention for your choice of user-interface framework.